# .htaccess how to use RedirectMatch

Tags: .htaccess

Since I changed the structure of my website, some of the links became broken. 
What rule should I write in .htaccess to fix the problem.

before it was like this

> /news/194-kozyrnyj-vecher-premier-ligi.html

and now it looks like this

> `/news/2-news/194-kozyrnyj-vecher-premier-ligi.html`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/news/2-news/(.*)
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)$ /news/2-news/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

should be:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/news/2-news/(.*)
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)$ /news/2-news/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

in your .htaccess file

Comment: RewriteEngine On - this was aleredy on, after I pasted the second expression there's still no redirect. I don't know what's is the problem

Comment: @user995195 Well then, you just need one. It turns on the engine that allows you to rewrite requests.

Comment: @user995195 Sorry for the trouble, tried the lazy way, here's the decent version. That RewriteCond will stop rewriting if we allready got redirected.

Comment: here's the part of .htacces that I have now and I still have the same problem

Comment: @user995195 Try putting the cond and rule above all others, it should take priority in processing. Also make sure its not your browser cache, try clearing it then try.